Many-to-many with details and temporal
I have two tables that are a many-to-many relationship. I use temporal tables to track the changes to the records, so that I can see updates and deletes for audits or to compare changes. In this scenario, I have many Teachers and many Courses. Each Teacher can teach many Courses and each Course can be taught by many Teachers. For each Teacher_Courses there is also data about that specific class, like NumberOfStudents or ClassPreferences. In the database, just because a Course gets deleted, I don't want to delete the details about that Teacher_Courses because other objects in the system rely on that data. So, I add those details to the Teacher_CoursesDetails table. I want to design a set of tables, using temporal tables as well, so that:

Allow for the deletion of CourseClass records (which will get added to the Temporal table)
Delete the Teacher_Courses record associated with the deleted CourseClass record
Preservethe Teacher_CoursesDetails record

Do not do this using "Soft Deletes". This would break the pattern of the rest of the database design.
Keep the temporal tables, so that all updates/deletes are tracked in their respective temporal table
public class TeacherClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;   
    public ICollection<Teacher_Courses> Teacher_Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher_Courses 
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }  // Add a primary key
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }     
    public TeacherClass TeacherClass { get; set; }
    public CourseClass CourseClass { get; set; }
    public Teacher_CoursesDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher_CoursesDetails 
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }  // Add a primary key
    public string ClassPreferences { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int NumberOfStudents { get; set; }
    public int Teacher_CoursesId { get; set; }
    public Teacher_Courses Teacher_Courses { get; set; }
}

public class CourseClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string CourseDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;     
    public ICollection<Teacher_Courses> Teacher_Courses { get; set; } 
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TeacherClass> TeacherClass { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher_Courses> Teacher_Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CourseClass> CourseClass { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher_CoursesDetails> Teacher_CoursesDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<TeacherClass>().ToTable("TeacherClass", c => c.IsTemporal());
        builder.Entity<CourseClass>().ToTable("CourseClass", c => c.IsTemporal());
        
        builder.Entity<Teacher_Courses>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Teacher_Courses", c => c.IsTemporal());
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            entity.HasOne(e => e.TeacherClass)
                .WithMany(s => s.Teacher_Courses)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.TeacherId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            entity.HasOne(e => e.CourseClass)
                .WithMany(c => c.Teacher_Courses)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.CourseId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });

        builder.Entity<Teacher_CoursesDetails>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Teacher_CoursesDetails", c => c.IsTemporal());
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Teacher_Courses)
                .WithOne(t => t.Details)
                .HasForeignKey<Teacher_CoursesDetails>(d => d.Teacher_CoursesId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        });
    }
}

The problem here is that when I try to delete a Teacher if there is a record in the Teacher_Courses I will get a FK constraint error. I can set Teacher_CoursesDetails OnDelete to SetNull but then when the user deletes the Teacher, it will set the Teacher_CoursesDetailsId to null and then I won't be able to query the data for later. Is there a way to fix this or is there a better way to do this?

is there a better way to do this - yes- soft deletes. I am fairly sure that any method you come up with to avoid soft deletes will introduce more complexity into your design that just going with soft deletes. Thats the normal way to solve this problem.

Otherwise you have a couple of options, either you don't have a FK between the tables (a FK is not required - but without one you run the risk of data integrity issues). That way when you delete from your main table and insert into your deleted table, if you keep the ID the same you still have a valid link, but to one of two tables, the live table or the deleted table.

The second way is tables which can link to deleted records have 2 FKs one to the live table and one to the deleted table and at deletion you swap them over. Slightly better from a data integrity perspective, but ugly from a data storage perspective. And both approaches require complexity is extracting data from the tables to take into account whether a record is deleted or not. Whereas a single deleted flag on a record is very simple and easy to detect in queries.

A FK constraint says that subrows appear elsewhere once. If that isn't the case for some subrows, don't declare a FK contraint. Figure out what constraint on the DB you actually want. Figure out what data you actually want to remember. (You might want to put certain things in certain tables so you can have a FK between certain ones.)

Please before considering posting: Pin down
code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error
message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your
question/problem/goal, with & without your particular
names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many
answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal &
unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at
[meta] & [meta.se]. How much research effort?
[ask] [Help] (Clearly this can be expected to be a faq.)

Using the suggested soft delete option was not aligned to the benefits of using the temporal tables, which I should track all changes, including deletes.  In the table I wanted to protect from deletion I changed the DeleteBehavior to ClientSetNull.  This way, when the parent object is deleted, the child records just have the foreign key set to null.  I then wrote middleware (using SaveChangesInterceptor) that would set another field (ProxyFK) to the value of the deleted key. This way, I can query based on that instead.
public class DeletedObjectInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
 {
     public override InterceptionResult<int> SavingChanges(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
     {
         var context = eventData.Context;
         if (context is null) return result;

         HandleDeletedConnectors(context);
         return result;
     }

     public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         var context = eventData.Context;
         if (context is null) return ValueTask.FromResult(result);

         HandleDeletedConnectors(context);
         return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
     }

     private void HandleDeletedConnectors(DbContext context)
     {
         var deletedItems = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<CourseClass>()
             .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
             .Select(e => e.Entity)
             .ToList();

         foreach (var c in deletedItems)
         {
             var relatedItems = context.Set<Teacher_Courses>()
                 .Where(mc => mc.CourseId == c.Id)
                 .ToList();

             foreach (var item in relatedItems)
             {
                 c.ProxyId = item.ConnectorId;                  
                 context.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
             }           
         }
     }
 }

and in Program.cs:
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    options.AddInterceptors(new DeletedObjectInterceptor());
});

